# Python remove control character when reading a text file

Tags: python

I'm tying to read a text file (.bcp), 100k lines at a time and then write to another file. However, a few rows contain the 'Substitute' character (Hex value: 001A) due to which the following code only seems to read until that row and nothing after that. I tried removing that character from the said rows before writing into the second file, but realised later (using `print(lines,"\n")`) that nothing is being read as soon as first such row is encountered.[I used this article to understand the 'Substitute' character and get the Hex value](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/14812/how-to-search-for-unknown-3-digit-characters-with-black-background/2), but basically when I open the file in Notepad++ it appears as 'SUB' with a black background. Please can someone help with a way to remove that character? Many thanks!

```
with open('input' + '\\' + file) as fIn:

while 1:
    lines = fIn.readlines(100000)
    print(lines,"\n")
    if not lines:
        break
    for line in lines :
        #line = re.sub(r'\x001A', '', line)
        line = line.replace(r'\x001A', '')
        line = line.replace(r'\x009D', '')
        fp.write(line)
```

EDIT: I've included a few example rows below. The first row is without the SUB character, the next two contain it. So when trying to read using `lines = fIn.readlines(100000)`, the code reads 1st line, then reads 2nd line until it encounters the character and then exits. You'll notice that when I've pasted the lines here the SUB character is automatically removed.

```
112411115ffg254b|302344|5.1234     |11111111|0|||1000|0|1015|          |0|5.1234     |11111111|1|0|1|1011|0|                                                                                                    |0
112400004eyg9gb5|302345|6.216     |22222222|0|||1001|0|1|          |0|6.216     |22222222|1|0|1|1|0|ù0                                                                                                |0
112200009ex12341|42581|3.119     |33333333|0|||1002|0|1|          |0|3.119     |33333333|1|0|1|1|1|Ù¸                                                                                                |0
```

[image]

Comment: Could you share one of those lines?

Comment: The article you are talking about says: And any of these characters may be found, individually, with the simple regex  `\x{NNNN}`. Have you tried this? Also, Can you post a few lines of your text file?

Comment: The SUB character shouldn't, per se, cause any problem reading the file. Is this on Windows (from the mention of Notepad++ I guess so)? Which Python version? What encoding is used in the file ?

Comment: Hi guys, I tried to include the lines here but when I post them the character gets automatically removed

Comment: I've attached a Notepad++ screenshot of the file if that helps. The file is encoded in ANSI

Comment: @Hoenie I've posted a sreenshot of a few lines (with and without the SUB character).

Comment: @DevanshSoni  I tried that further down the code but the issue lies in reading the row with the SUB character so my checking wasn't helpful in this scenario. I've posted a screenshot of the lines (can't copy and paste the rows as the character gets removed automatically

Comment: @Błotosmętek This is on Windows. Python version 2.7. The file is encoded in ANSI.

Comment: @Błotosmętek Thanks for providing that reference - it definitely seems helpful. However, what I'm not sure of is how to specify the SUB character in the `EOFCHAR = chr(26)` statement. I tried `EOFCHAR = '001A'` and `EOFCHAR = r'\x001A'` but that didn't work. Unsure of what the chr() value of the SUB character is.

Comment: SUB **is** chr(26)

Comment: @Błotosmętek Aah that's right. I tried that and has worked beautifully! thanks a ton!